# What is the limit ${{\lim }_{x\to\infty}}x^\epsilon$ for an infinitesimal $\epsilon$?

Tags: limits, infinitesimals

What is the limit

$${{\lim }_{x\to\infty}}x^\epsilon$$

for an infinitesimal $\epsilon$? Does it give zero or infinity?

Note that I'm considering the infinitesimals described in

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_infinitesimal_analysis

**EDIT:**

Since I was asked to show some of my own thoughts on the subject, I'd like to contribute the following:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^\epsilon = \lim_{x\to\infty} \exp(\log (x^\epsilon))= \lim_{x\to\infty} \exp(\epsilon\log(x))\\= \lim_{x\to\infty}(1+\epsilon\log(x))= \lim_{x\to\infty}(1+\epsilon)=1+\epsilon$$

Where we used a series expansion of $\exp(y)$ and the properties of infinitesimals $\epsilon^2=0$ and $a\epsilon=\epsilon$ for any number $a$. However, I am not sure if this is some sort of cheating my way around the limit at hand or not. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's an infinitesimal? Are you doing nonstandard analysis?

Comment: I am doing smooth infinitesimal analysis. As described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_infinitesimal_analysis

Comment: I wasn't “voicing my frustration”, but just asking for what setting you're in. There are *several* theories dealing with infinitesimals. Can you show some of your thoughts about the subject? You'll increase the chances to receive an answer.

Comment: I am sorry, I misunderstood. For the sake of flexibility, I am interested to learn the answer in any arbitrary but meaningful theory dealing with infinitesimals you prefer.

Comment: I have shown my thoughts on the problem in the edit. Does it make any sense?

Comment: How do you define $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ when $x$ is a function which takes on possibly infinitesimal values? I ask because, to my understanding, most nonstandard forms of analysis avoid discussing "limits" *per se* entirely, instead dealing with numbers which are infinitely close to the quantity of interest and then taking some sort of "standard part". In Robinson-style nonstandard analysis, this is literally the standard part operation; in smooth infinitesimal analysis, it arises from the fact that infinitesimals are defined to be nilpotent.

Comment: By the way, even the very first chapter of Spivaks Calculus book has some problems in it dealing with infinitesimals.

Comment: @Ian The operation of taking a limit towards infinity of a function provides sufficient information about the domain of the function at hand. I would not have asked a question which does not make sense to be asked. - Basically, you can consider $x\in\mathbb{R}$. It might very well be that it is not a standard thing to ask - that is why I am not sure what the result is and why I am asking in the first place.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the domain of $f$, I'm concerned about defining the limit operation in a productive way. The question itself seems odd, because at least Robinson-style nonstandard analysis would *define* "limits at infinity" by literally substituting in an infinite nonstandard number and seeing what happens. If the standard part of the answer doesn't depend on the infinite number you chose, then the limit exists, otherwise it doesn't (within the reals). I know less about smooth infinitesimal analysis, but I would think that a similar idea would apply there too.

Comment: OK, it seems what you describe might very well give an actually proper answer to my question. If you could write the result of "what happens" in an answer such that I can understand, I will be very happy to vote it up and accept it. (It does not matter that it would not be directly within smooth infinitesimal analysis. Any answer at all would be helpful!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Robinson framework, we can still define $x^\varepsilon$ to be $\exp(\varepsilon \log(x))$ when $\varepsilon$ is a positive infinitesimal and $x$ is a positive hyperreal number. We identify $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ (as it is formulated in the standard framework) with the standard part of $f(M)$ where $M$ is a positive infinite number, provided that the standard part does not depend on the choice of $M$. (Alternately, if it is always positive and infinite, we say the limit is $+\infty$, and if it is always negative and infinite, we say the limit is $-\infty$).

So here we substitute in an infinite number $M$, obtaining $M^\varepsilon = \exp(\varepsilon \log(M))$. This should immediately look like a problem, because $\varepsilon$ is infinitesimal while $\log(M)$ is infinite. Consequently $\varepsilon \log(M)$ might be infinite, if $M$ is for instance $\exp(\exp(1/\varepsilon))$. It might be finite, if $M$ is for instance $\exp(1/\varepsilon)$. Or it might be infinitesimal, if $M$ is for example $1/\varepsilon$.

We get a similar problem in the standard framework: if $f,g > 0$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)=0$ then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)^{g(x)}$ depends on how fast $f$ grows and how fast $g$ decays.

In this respect I would think that the limit simply can't be said to exist. Please note that I am not an expert on this subject, though; most of my knowledge is confined to proving basic standard theorems (e.g. Heine-Cantor) by nonstandard methods.

Comment: It still feels like a purely standard framework answer, where we only can say anything about the limit once we know the exact functional dependence of the entering elements on the limiting variable. Basically, thinking of an "infinitesimal" as something going to zero asymptotically, this might also be considered an order of limits problem. Oh, well. I guess this will have to suffice.

Comment: @Kagaratsch My understanding is that the actual nonstandard *theorems* of nonstandard analysis, that is, the ones that are defined purely in the nonstandard language, are not really of any particular interest to analysts.